# Getting Error while running ionic project [ng] panic: aborting due to terminal initialize failure

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

I have executed same program multiple time's but now I am trying to run the same program
using **ionic serve**

```
ionic serve
```

but getting an error :

```
[ng] panic: aborting due to terminal initialize failure
```